# Android O: IMPORTANCE_LOW notification that is expanded by default

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

In earlier versions of Android, it was possible to have a notification that did not show an icon in the status bar, but was expanded by default by using the `priority` setting.

```
// Hide status bar icon AND show notification as expanded
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
```

However, now when targeting Android 25 (Oreo) on a device running Android 26, it seems this isn't possible. When I set the importance level to `IMPORTANCE_MIN` I achieve the desired effect of not showing an icon in the status bar. However, the notification is "collapsed" by default.

```
// Hide status bar icon (but notification is collapsed)
NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
```

If I set the importance level to (or above) `IMPORTANCE_LOW` then the notification is expanded by default, but shows an icon in the status bar.

```
// Expand notification (but shows status bar icon)
NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
```

Is there any way to force the notification to be expanded by default when using `IMPORTANCE_MIN`? Perhaps I've missed some setting.

PS: Please do not suggest using `setSmallIcon` to transparent. That's just an old ugly hack that looks awful.

---

By "collapsed" and "expanded" I mean this:

Collapsed:
[image: collapsed]

Expanded:
[image: expanded]

---

---

**Source snippet**

```java
NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
notifManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setContent(myRemoteViews);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.status);
builder.setOngoing(true);
builder.setTicker(tickerText);
builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);

Notification notif = builder.build();
notifManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, notif);
```

Comment: Just curious if you ever found your answer to this question? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @user2101081 Nope :/ I ended up just going with IMPORTANCE_LOW and accepting the fact that the status icon will have to be shown, unfortunately.